# Tautological line bundle over rational projective space

Tags: vector-bundles, rational-numbers, p-adic-number-theory, projective-space, topological-k-theory

Is the tautological line  bundle over $\mathbb{Q}P^{n}$ a non trivial bundle?

Here, $\mathbb{Q}P^{n}$ has the natural topology induced from the  standard topology of $\mathbb{Q}$  as a  subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

What about if we change the topology by consideration of $p-$adic topology on rational numbers?

Comment: This is a very unnatural question to ask. $\mathbb{QP}^n$ is totally disconnected, so up to weak homotopy equivalence it's just discrete...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Thanks for the comment. for the moment lets forget the homotopy equivalent and focus on this pre-question: is  the canonical bundle  realy a vector bundle? is there local trivialization?the standard real or complex method does not work, I think.

Comment: It's certainly not a vector bundle in the usual sense, since its fibers aren't vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Of course i mean Q-vector bundle.

Comment: Right, but now you need to make a choice about what that means, namely: are you taking $\mathbb{Q}$ to have its usual topology or the discrete topology?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  The usual topology as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't understand how it's not obvious that there is a local trivialization.  All of functions involved in defining the standard local trivialization for the tautological bundle on projective space are rational functions, so they are well-defined and continuous over any topological field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A space is called *ultraparacompact* if every open cover can be refined to a cover by disjoint open sets.  Note that clearly any fiber bundle on an ultraparacompact space is trivial (just apply the definition to an open cover on which it is trivial).  So it suffices to show that $\mathbb{Q}P^n$ is ultraparacompact (with either the standard topology or the $p$-adic topology).  More generally, I will prove the following:

> **Theorem**: Any countable space with a basis of clopen sets is ultraparacompact.

Proof: Let $Q=\{q_n\}$ be a countable space with a basis of clopen sets and let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover.  Define a refinement of $\mathcal{U}$ by induction.  First, let $V_1$ be any clopen set containing $q_1$ which is contained in some element of $\mathcal{U}$.  Next, if $q_2\in V_1$, let $V_2=V_1$; otherwise, let $V_2$ be a clopen set containing $q_2$ which is contained in some element of $\mathcal{U}$ and disjoint from $V_1$.  Continue by induction, adding clopen sets contained in some element of $\mathcal{U}$, containing the next $q_n$, and disjoint from the clopen sets we've chosen so far.  In the end, we get an open cover $\{V_n\}$ refining $\mathcal{U}$ consisting of disjoint clopen sets.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting and perfect answer.