# Is $\mathbb{Q}P^{n}$ less studied/less useful than $\mathbb{R}P^{n}, \mathbb{C}P^{n}$?

Tags: soft-question, projective-space

I was wondering why we hardly ever talk about the rational projective spaces. We frequently use the real, [complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22complex%20projective%20space%22), finite or even [quaternionic](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22quaternionic%20projective%20space%22) ones, but for instance there is apparently only [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522214) question on M.SE about $\mathbb{Q}P^{n}$.

Is it true that $\mathbb{Q}P^{n}$ less studied/less useful than the other projective spaces? Is there any particular reason for this?

I can try to make my thoughts more clear/more precise if necessary. But I hope I'm not the only one who have rarely seen $\mathbb{Q}P^{n}$.

Thank you for your comments!

Comment: Well, it's not a manifold.

Comment: @arctic tern: that's a good point indeed.

Comment: One can obviously study $\mathbb P^n_k$ for all field $k$, including $\mathbb Q$. But we normally use the tariski topology of $k$. If you use the standard subspace topology, the question you linked show that $\mathbb {QP}^n$ is not that interesting.

Comment: We can even look at the [octonionic projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_plane)… Sometimes, in the context of modular forms, we can consider the rational projective line (i.e. $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb Q)$, projective line over $\Bbb Q$), e.g. see at the bottom of p. 89 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ty-IAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algebraic geometers in fact study an object that is just called $\mathbb{P}^n$. It is a [scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(mathematics)), and it contains the data of $K \mathbb{P}^n$ for any field $K$ (but is more general than this, e.g. $K$ can be replaced by an arbitrary commutative ring; at this level of generality the definition becomes more subtle).

As mentioned in the comments, what makes $\mathbb{RP}^n$ and $\mathbb{CP}^n$ (and $\mathbb{HP}^n$ and, when $n = 1, 2$, $\mathbb{OP}^n$) special is that they are also smooth manifolds, so are also studied by algebraic topologists, differential geometers, etc.

$\mathbb{QP}^1$ in particular also makes an appearance in the theory of modular forms as the set of [cusps](http://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/modform.html).